# Create Azure IOT Hub w/ New-AzureRmIotHub

Tags: azure, c#-4.0, iot, azure-iot-hub

Attempting to write a PowerShell script to automate creation of an Azure IOT Hub resource. Using the function New-AzureRmIotHub to create the hub. All is well, except that I can't figure out how to define some of the more advanced settings. In particular, I want to define the Cloud2Device Partitions parameter. This setting is under the Monitoring settings within the Azure portal. I was thinking it can be set through 'Properties', but I can't find any doc for this.. Here is what I came up with, but it does not work...

```
$c2dprops = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.IotHub.Models.PSCloudToDeviceProperties -Property @{Partions=32} 
$props = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.IotHub.Models.PSIotHubInputProperties -Property @{CloudToDevice=$c2dprops} 

$IotHub = @{
  ResourceGroupName = $resourcegroup;
  Name = $hubname;
  SkuName = $skuname;
  Units = $units;
  Location = $location;
  Properties = $props;
};
New-AzureRmIotHub @IotHub;
```

Comment: Have you check [PSOperationsMonitoringProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.iothub/Set-AzureRmIotHub?view=azurermps-4.1.0) ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing the same thing - you may be ahead of me.
I've found the documentation pretty sparse.  Unfortunately I've had to just look at the C# implementation of the PowerShell types.

The good news is that it's on GitHub, see https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell.  There is good stuff in https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/tree/preview/src/ResourceManager/IotHub and below.  I suggest you Clone the entire Repository and then open IotHub.sln in Visual Studio and read the code.